# issue with comparison between php and select mysql

Tags: php, mysql, select, null

I've been looking for an answer to my problems for few hours, but it seems I don't look at the right place, or I'm the first to have a so twisted programing style.

I have a  in my php code, with some input inside, that put every informations in a database.
After that, I have another form, with others input that allows me to make some research in my DB.

Here the troubles comes.

If I want to find something in aprticular, I have to fill all the inputs, like "name", "nickname", "computer name", and it finds it well, with a "select * from db where name=name and nickname=nickname etc...".

But if i want to find every computers that one person have, I would just put his name, and I want that it shows me every row that contain that name.

In other words, I want that my MySQL query just ignore the variables that are not completed in the form, I set them to NULL by default, but I have the feeling that mysql think it is a value, and compare it to the data in the db.

If I only fill 1 input, it shows nothing, I have to complete all the fields..

Code incoming, don't be rude, I'm pretty beegining... and also sorry for my english. :(

in advance, thank you for your help.

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css" type="text/css" media="screen" /> 


<title>TITRE</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php

//initializing everything to NULL, in case nothing is typed in the fields

if(!empty($_POST['techName']))
$techNom = $_POST['techName'];
else
$techNom = NULL;

if(!empty($_POST['techNickname']))
$techPrenom = $_POST['techNickname'];
else
$techPrenom = NULL;

if(!empty($_POST['userName']))
$userNom = $_POST['userName'];
else
$userNom = NULL;

if(!empty($_POST['userNickname']))
$userPrenom = $_POST['userNickname'];
else
$userPrenom = NULL;

if(!empty($_POST['assetTag']))
$tag = $_POST['assetTag'];
else
$tag = NULL;

if(!empty($_POST['serial']))
$serial = $_POST['serial'];
else
$serial = NULL;

if(!empty($_POST['cpuName']))
$cpuName = $_POST['cpuName'];
else
$cpuName = NULL;

if(!empty($_POST['modele']))
$modele = $_POST['modele'];
else
$modele = NULL;

if(isset($_POST['fixe']))
$type = $_POST['fixe'];
else
$type = NULL;

if(isset($_POST['portable']))
$type1 = $_POST['portable'];
else
$type1 = NULL;

if(!empty($_POST['date']))
$date = $_POST['date'];
else
$date = NULL;
?>

<h1>Visualisation de poste utilisateur</h1>
<ul id=menu>
<table>
<tr><td><a href="index.html">Accueil</a></td></tr>
<tr><td><a href="saisie.html">Saisie de matériel entrant</a></td></tr>
<tr><td><a href="visualisation.html">Visualisation du matériel</a></td></tr>
<tr><td><a href="visuGlobale.php">Visualisation du stock</a></td></tr>
<tr><td><a href="suppression.html">Suppression d'élément</a></td></tr>
<tr><td><a href="ajout_user.html">Ajout d'utilisateur</a></td></tr>
<tr><td><a href="visu_users.php">Visualisation des utilisateurs</a></td></tr>

</table>
</ul>

<FORM method="POST" action="">
<input type=hidden value='0' name=portable>
<input type=hidden value='0' name=fixe>
<table>
<tr><td colspan=4 align=center><b>TECHNICIEN</b></td></tr>
<tr><td>Prénom :</td><td><input type=text size=20 name=techNickname value=<?php echo $techPrenom ?>></td><td>Nom :</td><td><input type=text size=20 name=techName value=<?php echo $techNom?>></td></tr>
<tr><td colspan=4 align=center><b>UTILISATEUR</b></td></tr>
<tr><td>Prénom :</td><td><input type=text size=20 name=userNickname value=<?php echo $userPrenom?>></td><td>Nom :</td><td><input type=text size=20 name=userName value=<?php echo $userNom?>></td></tr>
<tr><td>TAG :</td><td><input type=text size=20 name=assetTag value=<?php echo $tag?>></td><td>N° de série :</td><td><input type=text size=20 name=serial value=<?php echo $serial?>></td></tr>
<tr><td>Nom de machine :</td><td><input type=text size=20 name=cpuName value=<?php echo $cpuName ?>></td><td>modèle :</td><td><input type=text size=20 name=modele value=<?php echo $modele ?>></td></tr>
<tr><td><label for="1">Portable</label></td><td><input type=checkbox name=portable checked="true" value=<?php $type1?>></td>
<td><label for="2">Fixe</label></td><td><input type=checkbox name=fixe value=<?php $type ?>></td></tr>
<tr><td>Date d'installation :</td><td><input type=text size=20 name=date placeholder="jj-mm-aaaa" value=<?php echo $date ?>></td></tr>
<tr><td colspan=2 ><INPUT type=submit Value=Envoyer></td><td><INPUT type=hidden name=afficher value=ok></td></tr>

</table>


<?php

//connecting DB
try
{
    $bdd = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=base_test', 'root', '', array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION));
}
catch (Exception $e)
{
        die('Erreur : ' . $e->getMessage());
}

//some test that didn't help me well

/*$req = $bdd->prepare('SELECT * FROM table_utilisateurs WHERE userNom=:userNom
                        AND userPrenom=:userPrenom');
$req->execute(array('userNom' => $userNom,
                    'userPrenom' => $userPrenom));*/

$req = $bdd->prepare('SELECT * FROM table_utilisateurs WHERE userNom=:userNom 
                        AND userPrenom=:userPrenom
                        AND techNom=:techNom
                        AND techPrenom=:techPrenom
                        AND assetTag=:assetTag
                        AND serialNumber=:serialNumber
                        AND modele=:modele
                        AND type=:type
                        AND dateInstall=:dateInstall
                        AND name=:name');


$req->execute(array('userNom' => $userNom,
                    'userPrenom' => $userPrenom,
                    'techNom' => $techNom,
                    'techPrenom' => $techPrenom,
                    'assetTag' => $tag,
                    'serialNumber' => $serial,
                    'modele' => $modele,
                    'type' => $type,
                    'dateInstall' => $date,
                    'name' => $cpuName));





while($donnees = $req->fetch()){
    echo $donnees['userNom'], " ", $donnees['userPrenom'], " ", $donnees['techNom'], " ", $donnees['techPrenom'], " ", $donnees['assetTag'], " ", $donnees['serialNumber'], " ", 
                            $donnees['modele'], " ", $donnees['type'], " ", $donnees['dateInstall'], " ", $donnees['name'];

                            echo '<br/>';
    };


    $req->closeCursor();
    /*$donnees = $req->fetch();
    echo $donnees['userNom'], " ", $donnees['userPrenom'], " ", $donnees['techNom'], " ", $donnees['techPrenom'], " ", $donnees['assetTag'], " ", $donnees['serialNumber'], " ", 
                            $donnees['modele'], " ", $donnees['type'], " ", $donnees['dateInstall'], " ", $donnees['name'];*/



?>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: All your `name=xxx` need to be quoted `name="xxx"` same thing for `value=` and `type=` - the list seems to be growing as I go...

Comment: I think its because you are passing in NULL for anything that isn't input so the query is searching for NULL values so nothing is returned. If you use your post array directly you can loop through that to build the where clause and then pass the array into the execute method. That way you can also get rid of all those conditionals.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @David jones suggest.
You can build custom where condition according to inputs entered by user in search field.

```
$where_cond="";

if($_POST['techName']!="")
{
$where_cond.="technamecolumn=".$_POST['techName'];
} 

if($_POST['username']!="")
{
$where_cond.="usernamecolumn=".$_POST['userName'];
}
```

same for other
Now write your query as

```
$q="SELECT technanmcolumn,usernamecolumn FROM tablename WHERE ".$where_cond;
```

This query include those values that are entered by user to search in where condition.
Execute that query and get result.
I will suggest you to use switch case instead of IF conditions.

Comment: It might work, I have to make some changes to my code, because it now makes me lots of new errors, but nothing impossible to fix.
I will try to make that work, and keep you informed, thank you